# Multi dimensional array - no output

Tags: multidimensional-array

I'm doing a two-dimensional array exercise from the book Beginner Javascript, but I have no output for the code in browser. Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Chapter 2, Example 9</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    var personnel = [];

    var personnel [0]  = [];
    var personnel [0] [0] = "Name0";
    var personnel [0] [1] = "Age0";
    var personnel [0] [2] = "Address0";

    var personnel [1]  = [];
    var personnel [1] [0] = "Name1";
    var personnel [1] [1] = "Age1";
    var personnel [1] [2] = "Address1";

    var personnel [1]  = [];
    var personnel [1] [0] = "Name1";
    var personnel [1] [1] = "Age1";
    var personnel [1] [2] = "Address1";

    document.write ("Name: " + personnel [1] [0] + "<br/>");
    document.write ("Age: " + personnel [1] [1] + "<br/>");
    document.write ("Address: " + personnel [1] [2] + "<br/>");

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Defining variable personnel once is enough. 'var' words from the next lines are causing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's

```
personnel [0]  = [];
personnel [0] [0] = "Name0";
```

not

```
var personnel [0]  = [];
var personnel [0] [0] = "Name0";
```

One "var" is enough